# Angular calendar - PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using PrimeNG calendar component with angular 4. It fits most of my requirement except I don't see a way to show week numbers in component.

Am I overlooking something simple or if it is not supported yet then is there a way I can do it ?

Thanks

Comment: It is not supported, at least not yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Any workaround?

Comment: Not as far as I know, you can ask on PrimeNG's GitHub repository, you will get more info there for sure.

Comment: If it's an option for you, you can look at datepickers from other libraries. I know http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker and https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api both are capable of showing week numbers.

Comment: Yeah I tried them but they don't fit well in my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but the latest version of `PrimeNG calendar` does now support displaying the `week number`. Setting `[showWeek]= "true"` will display them.

Here is the latest documentation.
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar